# Define the mass function

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the following experiment: A coin is tossed with probability $\alpha \in (0,1)$ of head and a dice is rolled at the same time. Define the following random variable:

\begin{equation*}
        X = \begin{cases} 
        \text{number in the face of the dice} \ , \ \text{if heads} \\ 
        \text{number in the face of the dice + 2} \ , \text{if tails}
        \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Define the probability mass function of $X$.

Well, i think that the elements of the random variable are something like $(1,H),(2,H),\dots,(6,H),(3,T),\dots, (9,T)$. The probability mass function would be something like $$P(X=x)=P(X=(n,H))=\alpha\cdot \frac{1}{6}$$ for $n \in \{1,2,\dots,6\}$. This makes sense? I'm really lost i'm this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be the *result* of the die throw, and $T$ be the *count* of tails on the coin toss, and so: $X{=}D{+}2T$.

Now when the coin shows heads, $X$ may be $1,2,3,4,5,$ or $6$ with equal probability, else when the coin shows tails, $X$ may be $3,4,5,6,7,$ or $8$ with equal probability (ie $1/6$ each case).

So all up, $X$ may be $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ with various probabilities; and so, because the coin is heads with probability $\alpha$ and tails with probability $(1-\alpha)$, we get:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{=}x)&=\mathsf P(T{=}0,D{=}x)+\mathsf P(T{=}1,D{=}x{-}2)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(T{=}0)\,\mathsf P(D{=}x)+\mathsf P(T{=}1)\,\mathsf P(D{=}x{-}2)\\[1ex]&=\alpha\,\mathsf P(D{=}x)+(1-\alpha)\,\mathsf P(D{=}x{-}2)\\[2ex]&=\begin{cases}?\qquad\qquad&:&x\in\{1,2\}\\?&:&x\in\{3,4,5,6\}\\?&:&x\in\{7,8\}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

These are the outcomes, with entries in the first column having chance $\frac 1 {6}\alpha$ of occurring and entries in the second column having pure luck $\frac 1 6(1-\alpha)$, except four of the outcomes occur twice each, with probability $\frac \alpha 6+\frac{1-\alpha} 6 =\frac 1 6$ of occurring.